# heroku rake migrate not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am just trying to simply do the following:

```
my@ubuntu-lappy:~/rails/app_soft$ heroku rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
Please install the  adapter: `gem install activerecord--adapter` (no such file to load -- active_record/connection_adapters/_adapter)
```

What am i doing wrong?

In the past I've successfully ran heroku rake db:migrate

`gem list` shows

```
activerecord (2.3.5, 2.2.2)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if the app gets instantiated incorrectly. As a workaround you can rename the app to get it out of the way and create a new one. You'll likely need to open a support request to get the wedged app deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and suspected that is may be a problem with the instance you're currently on.

When I try to run "heroku info", it gives me an internal server error.  It may have something to do with the heroku's database.yml [referencing a bad value](http://www.pubbs.net/ruby/200909/125939/).

~~~
I heard back from david@heroku. Apparently my app was 'wedged', so the solution was to create it again. I'm still waiting to hear back on what 'wedged' means and how to destroy that stale app.
Other than that it's working for me.

Comment: heard back from david@heroku.  Apparently my app was 'wedged', so the solution was to create it again.  I'm still waiting to hear back on what 'wedged' means and how to destroy that stale app.  Other than that it's working for me.